# Unable to access test java files from src java files

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit4, classnotfoundexception

I have created a maven project. In src/main/java one of my java file(say package.name.Loader.java) is using Class.forname(String className) method to load class at runtime. For this purpose I have created a sample test java file(say package.test.SampleTestFile) in src/test/java. While doing JUnit testing, When I am passing name to Loader.java, I am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. Need help.

Sample: 
src/main/java

```
    package package.name;
    public class Loader {

    public Class<?> loadFile(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
      return Class.forName(className);
    }
   }
```

src/test/java

```
package package.test;
                public class SampleTestFile {

                    public void printHello() {
                        System.out.println("Hello World");
                    }
                }
```

src/test/java

```
package package.unit.test;

                import static org.junit.Assert.*;

                import package.name.Loader;
                import package.test.SampleTestFile;
                public class LoaderTest {

                    @test
                    public void testLoadFile() {
                        Loader loader = new Loader;
                        Class<?>clazz = loader.loadFile("package.test.SampleTestFile");
                        assertEquals(SampleTestFile.class, clazz);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have package name as package.test/package.unit.test ?

Comment: java does not allow to create packages with name package.name/package.test/package.unit.test. Please re-check again.

Comment: @ShekharKhairnar  I understand package name cannot have package keyword in it. package.test/package.unit.test is just for readability. You can consider it as org.rdx.test/org.rdx.unit.test